# First time screen

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, splash-screen

I'm developing a windows phone 8 application in C#.

The application needs to load some resources from the server *only* on first use. These resources will later be cached locally so they won't have to be loaded every time later on.

#### Basically, I want to redirect users to a "Preparing Application" screen until the app is ready but *only on the first go*.

Currently, I send users to the "Preparing" page every time and redirect if the resources are available - but the problem is **I don't have `NavigationService` ready before the `Loaded` event** so the users actually see the "Preparing" page each time. This is my current code:

```
Loaded += async (x, args) =>
    {
       await Task.WhenAll(new List<Task> {fetchFirstResource,fetchSecondResource});
       NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/RealPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    };
```

### tl;dr;

How do I change the application start page during runtime? Or alternatively - how do I redirect before the load event to another screen?

<sup>Reading and detailed answers appreciated, alternative approaches to this problem also appreciated</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should us an `UriMapper`, it will allow you to redirect the app to a specific page based on conditions. Here is how to do:

Set the `DefaultTask.NavigationPage`attribute of the WMAppManifest.xml file to a inexistant page

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="Start.xaml" />
```

At the end of the Application constructor in the App.xaml.cs, set the `RootFrame.UriMapper` to a new UriMapper that does the redirection based on a condition:

```
// Store a bool in the IsolatedStorage.Settings that indicates if the download has already been made
// and use it to know if you need to redirect or not
bool downloadRequired = true; // We set it to true just for the test
var mapper = new UriMapper();
string page = "/MainPage.xaml";

if (downloadRequired)
    page = "/DownloadData.xaml";

mapper.UriMappings.Add(new UriMapping
{
    Uri = new Uri("/Start.xaml", UriKind.Relative),
    MappedUri = new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative)
});

this.RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by checking for an existing local file with the data you need, e.g.:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
    if (store.FileExists("cache.dat")) {
        // Deserialize cache.dat and load real page.
    } else {
        // Load preparing page, begin building cache, serialize cache for next run.
    }
}
```

You can do this in the boot-up sequence, in-code navigation instead of StartupURI.